# How to create a jar file using Cygwin?

Tags: java, jar, makefile, cygwin

I have a program in java which uses a lot of classes and now I wish to make a single .jar file for all of them. How do I do this using cygwin in windows 8.

My adviser told me to use cygwin and type make in my devel and jars directory, however after doing this I am unable to figure where the jar file is create.

Thanks for your time and responses.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that :

1. Create a manifest file. for ex, i've created a `MANIFEST.MF` in the same folder :

   ```
   Main-Class: HelloWorld
   ```

   (don't forget the carriage return at the end)
2. Compile your java code :

   ```
   javac.exe *.java
   ```
3. Create the executable JAR file :

   ```
   jar.exe cvmf MANIFEST.MF hello_word.jar *.class
   ```
4. Execute the .jar :

   ```
   java.exe -jar hello_word.jar
   ```

You can specify the path when you create the jar file :

```
jar.exe cvmf MANIFEST.MF /path/you/want/hello_word.jar *.class
```